# How to specify third party jar path, while running a jar file in mac terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I have built a jar file from our project in eclipse.
But while running the jar file from terminal (mac os), I am getting third party jar issue. I have included third party dependent jars in my project build path.
I am running a jar file from terminal as "java -jar MyApp.jar"

But it throws ClassNotFoundException for third party classes.

Please let me know if anyone having idea about how to specify third party jar paths while running jar file.

Thanks in advance.
Ram

Comment: Use either the `-cp` or `-classpath` option

Comment: If I add the third party jar path in manifest file, it is accepting with Class-Path: tag. But I have to include almost 50 jar files. If I include them with space, it gives the error as line is too long. What is the solution for this?

Comment: The manifest is probably the better approach.  Consider using a build process like Ant or maybe an IDE which will do it for you